# Animated cursor on framer

Tags: animation, cursor, framer-motion, framerjs, iframe-resizer

I have been trying to achieve the animated cursor functionality on framer using react code but have not been getting any result. please help me with the code

I have tried to write the code in react but not getting result

Comment: It's pretty difficult for anyone to help you with your code because you didn't include it at all. And if "help me with the code" means "code this for me", then I doubt anyone will help you.